# Identifying data compression on a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am staring at many rows like this:

[image: sql-table-row]

How can I find out how the column `data` has been compressed please?

Comment: You're going to have to ask whomever is responsible for putting data into that table how that data is formatted. AFAIK, there's no feature in SQL Server that will compress just a column of data.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your table is compressed by reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/09/03/how-to-identify-compressed-tables-before-restoring-migrating-database-to-any-edition-other-than-enterprise-edition-of-sql-server-2008.aspx). It also specifies how to decompress your data.

However, from your output it looks as if data is encrypted. Maybe it is done in the application layer, as SQL seems to output VARBINARY from [encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331(v=sql.110).aspx) at displays as hex string when displayed in SSMS.

Comment: SQL Server data compression is transparent to the data consumer. That is, it wouldn't produce data like the OP is seeing.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I have updated the answer accordingly.